# How does Apache merge multiple matching Location sections

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm working on some basic apache configuration, but I don't understand precisely how apache merges different `<Location>` sections when several of them match an incoming requests URL. The [apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/sections.html) in its "How the sections are merged" chapter is a little bit confusing when it comes to the order/priority of several matching sections of the same type.

For example, imagine the following apache configuration (ignore whether the actual contents make sense or not, I'm only interested in the application order of each rule/section):

```
<Location / >
  ProxyPass http://backend.com/
  Order allow,deny
  Satisfy any
</Location>

<Location /sub/foo>
  Order allow,deny
</Location>

<Location /sub >
  Order deny,allow
  Require valid-user
  Satisfy all
</Location>

<Location /doesnt/match >
  ProxyPass !
</Location>
```

Now if a client makes a request to `/sub/foobar`, which is the final configuration that will be applied to this request?

Is the applied configuration the equivalent of:

```
# All the directives contained in all the matchin Locations in declaration order
ProxyPass http://backend.com/
Order allow,deny
Satisfy any
Order allow,deny
Order deny,allow
Require valid-user
Satisfy all
```

or maybe

```
# same as above, but with longest matching path last
ProxyPass http://backend.com/
Order allow,deny
Satisfy any
Order deny,allow
Require valid-user
Satisfy all
Order allow,deny
```

or something completely different.

Thanks for your help, I'm really confusing.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The order of merging is fairly complicated, and it's easy to be caught out by exceptions... The apache doc is "[How the sections are merged](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/sections.html#merging)"

According to that documentation, the order of merging of sections is done by processing all of the matching entries for each match type in the order that they are encountered in the configuration files, with the last match winning. (with the exception of <Directory>, which is treated in order of path specificity).

The order of types is `Directory`, `DirectoryMatch`, `Files`, and finally `Location`.   Later matches overwrite earlier matches. (*ProxyPass and Alias are treated differently again, see note at end)

And there are several important exceptions to these rules that apply to using ProxyPass, and ProxyPass in a <Location> section. (see below)

So from your example above requesting http://somehost.com/sub/foobar with the follwing config;

```
<Location / >
  ProxyPass http://backend.com/
  Order allow,deny
  Satisfy any
</Location>

<Location /sub/foo>
  Order allow,deny
</Location>

<Location /sub >
  Order deny,allow
  Require valid-user
  Satisfy all
</Location>

<Location /doesnt/match >
  ProxyPass !
</Location>
```

It would accumulate the following directives ....

```
  ProxyPass http://backend.com/
  Order allow,deny
  Satisfy any
  Order allow,deny
  Order deny,allow
  Require valid-user
  Satisfy all
```

With the later matches eliminating the previous duplicates, resulting in;

```
  ProxyPass http://backend.com/
  Order deny,allow
  Require valid-user
  Satisfy all
```

**Explanation**
Later matches overwrite earlier matches with the exception of `<Directory>` where matches are processed in the order: shortest directory component to longest.

> So for example,
>   `<Directory /var/web/dir>`
>   will be processed before
>   `<Directory /var/web/dir/subdir>`
>   regardless of what order those directives were specified in the config, and the more specific match wins.

Any matching `Location` directive will always override a previously matching `Directory` directive.

The basic idea is that for a request like `GET /some/http/request.html` internally it will be translated to a location in the filesystem via an `Alias`, `ScriptAlias` or for a normal file location under the `DocumentRoot` for the VirtualHost that it matched.

So a request will have the following properties which it uses for matching:
     `Location: /some/http/request.html 
     File: /var/www/html/mysite/some/http/request.html
Directory: /var/www/html/mysite/some/http`

Apache will then apply in turn all of the `Directory` matches, in the order of directory specificity, from the config, and then in turn apply `DirectoryMatch`, `Files`, and finally `Location` matches in the order in which they are encountered.

So `Location` overrides `Files`, which overrides `DirectoryMatch`, with paths matching `Directory` at the lowest priority. Hence in your example above, a request to `/sub/foobar` would match the first 3 Location in order, hence the last one wins for conflicting directives.

(You are right that it is not clear from the docs how some of the edge cases are resolved, its possible that any `allow from *` type directives would be connected to the associated `Order allow,deny`, but I didn't test that. Also what happens if you match `Satisfy Any` but you have previously collected an `Allow from *`...)

**interesting note about ProxyPass and Alias**

Just to be annoying, `ProxyPass` and `Alias` appears to work in the other direction.... ;-) It basically hits the first match, then stops and uses that!

> ```
> Ordering ProxyPass Directives
>
> The configured ProxyPass and ProxyPassMatch rules are 
> checked in the order of configuration. 
> The first rule that matches wins. So
> usually you should sort conflicting ProxyPass rules starting with the
> longest URLs first. Otherwise later rules for longer URLS will be
> hidden by any earlier rule which uses a leading substring of the URL.
> Note that there is some relation with worker sharing.
>
> For the same reasons exclusions must come before the general 
> ProxyPass directives.
> ```

so basically, Alias and ProxyPass directives have to be specified, most specific first;

```
Alias "/foo/bar" "/srv/www/uncommon/bar"
Alias "/foo"     "/srv/www/common/foo"
```

and

```
ProxyPass "/special-area" "http://special.example.com" smax=5 max=10
ProxyPass "/" "balancer://mycluster/" stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid nofailover=On
```

However, as @orev has pointed out. You can have a ProxyPass directive in a Location directive, and so a more specific ProxyPass in a Location will beat out any previously found ProxyPass.

Comment: Thanks for flagging the warning about Ordering ProxyPass Directives. Saved me a great deal of headache

Comment: Regarding `ProxyPass` _"working in the other direction"_, this is only true if they're outside of a `<Location>`.  Inside a `<Location>`, the rules of merging `<Location>` are followed, meaning you want your least-specific `<Location>` directives to come _before_ the more specific ones.  This allows the more specific ones to override the less specific directives.  You can only have one `ProxyPass` per `<Location>`.

Comment: I don't know if things have changed since 2012, but an access to `/sub/foobar` in Apache 2.4 does *not* match `<Location /sub/foo>`, so some bits of the text above are incorrect. See the text for `/private1other` in the `Location` docs.

Answer (score 0):

If you nest section (eg. ): Nested sections are merged after non-nested sections of the same type. This means if you add an  block to a non-nested configuration your last-matching section changes.