# Apache merging location sections (again)

Tags: apache-2.4

I read [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/391488/110724) to a similar question asked some time ago, and it made good sense and matched the Apache 2.4 documentation. But I had the following experience, which seems to contradict that answer and the documentation. Consider the following directives:

```
<Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/foo">
    AuthName "foo user"
    AuthType Basic
    Authuserfile /opt/lampp/passwds/foo.users
</Directory>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName   foo.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/foo/public"
    ErrorLog     "logs/foo.error_log"
    <Location />
        Require valid-user
    </Location>
    <Location /wp/feed>
        Require all granted
    </Location>
    CustomLog    "logs/foo.access_log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The intent, clearly, is to protect all urls with http basic authentication, ***except*** for urls below `/wp/feed`. But after reloading apache, I got prompted for credentials when going to `/wp/feed`. That url matches both of the Location paths, so apache should have processed `Require valid-user` followed by `Require all granted`, and I should not have been prompted. Just for "fun", I tried switching the order of the location blocks, but still got prompted. The only thing I could find that worked as I intended was to remove the location block for "/" entirely. To me, that also was unexpected behavior because in that case there were no `Require valid-user` directives at all that should have been applied to urls not matching `/wp/feed`. And yet they were applied, since I got prompted for all urls that did not match `/wp/feed`.

Can anyone explain this? Am I just missing the boat in understanding the answer and [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/sections.html#merging)?

I had no problem specifying this behavior with nginx directives, where the longest prefix match generally wins. If what I got really is the expected behavior, how can I get what I want with apache?

Comment: Are there by any chance `.htaccess` files that are locally overriding the config set from your main Apache configuration ?

Comment: Good question, but I think not. There are two .htaccess files in existence. One is at /wp/.htaccess which is the standard one for WordPress sites with custom permalinks that use mod_rewrite to force references to non-existent files to wp/index.php. And the other at /,htaccess that similarly uses mod-rewrite to force references to the root to go to /wp. No directives related to authentication or authorization at all.

Comment: If there are references  to non-existing files in the html code of your `/wp/feed` or to files (css , .js , images) in a higher directory that will also result in an authentication pop up

Comment: Good observation. But the thing is that removing the <Location /> block entirely gives exactly what I want: no popups for /wp/feed, but popups for every other location. I'm surprised that I would get prompted to authenticate at all with no Require valid-user directives anywhere in the configuration. Can you explain that?

Comment: Now I'm really confused. Checking the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require) once more, it says the allowed context for Require directives is "directory, .htaccess". VirtualHost is not included. But <Location> is only allowed in contexts "server config, virtual host". And yet many examples show Require being used in Location blocks, and clearly the use in my Location block for /wp/feed does work. This is crazy!

Comment: Were you ever able to come to a resolution on this? I am seeing a very similar problem and not sure how to make it work the right way. Specifically: requests for /folder/ need to belong to users group and requests to /folder/admin/ need to belong to admins group.

Comment: @Joe I'm sorry, no, I never figured this out. I was already using nginx to serve static files and as a reverse proxy to an apache server for everything else, so I just put the access controls in the nginx configuration where they worked sensibly, and stopped playing with it.