# Multiple "Location" sections with different handlers aren't combined anymore in apache2 after upgrade

Tags: php, web-server, apache2, uwsgi, piwik

I have a website with the following configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.it

<Location />
    SetHandler uwsgi-handler
    uWSGISocket /var/sitedir/moin.sock
</Location>

<Location /piwik/>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</Location>

<Directory "/var/piwik/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</Directory>

Alias /piwik/ "/var/piwik/"

</VirtualHost>
```

... including a moinmoin wiki and a Matomo instance; but since some system upgrade, when I visit `http://example.it/piwik`, I get the *source* of the `index.php` file inside `/var/piwik/` - it is not executed.

I know this suggests of some php problem - but if I remove the two `Location` sections, Matomo works just fine at `http://example.it/piwik` (Moinmoin clearly stops working). So it is really a problem of this configuration.
If instead I only remove the second `Location` section (Matomo's one), then `http://example.it/piwik` is served by uwsgi (Moinmoin).

So summing up,

1. If the only section is Matomo's `Directory` section, then its `SetHandler` directive does its job.
2. If `/piwik/` doesn't have its own `Location`, then the `SetHandler` inside its `Directory` section is not honored: this is as expected, since [`Location` sections should have priority over `Directory` sections](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html#merging).
3. However, if `/piwik/` does have its own `Location`, then its `SetHandler` statement *should* be honored, because it comes later. And in fact, something happens, because the request is not served by uwsgi. But it's not served as php either.

What is going wrong? Notice that I'm sure Moinmoin and Matomo worked both fine before a system upgrade, and while I'm not sure anymore how exactly the config file was, I'm pretty sure I tried all the combinations including the one that used to work.

EDIT: related, but does not explain my problem: [How does Apache merge multiple matching Location sections](https://serverfault.com/questions/391457/how-does-apache-merge-multiple-matching-location-sections)

Comment: probably a dumb question, but should there be a trailing / in the *Alias /piwik* bit ?(*Alias /piwik/ "/var/piwik/"*). If not, I'll back away slowly into the hedge now...

Comment: Smock, I _think_ you are perfectly right, and I edited the config file above accordingly (removing the / was some failed experiment of mine)... but the problem unfortunately remains.

Comment: Ahh :-/ worth a shot :(